# write UUID in Vertica with jooQ

Tags: jooq, vertica

I don't have jOOQ generated classes, so, I want to use my class and write it to vertica.

```
    Table<Record> table = DSL.table(DATA_TABLE_NAME);    
    for (Data d : data) {
          dsl.insertInto(table, Arrays.asList(
             DSL.field(name("uuid"), SQLDataType.UUID)
          ))
          .values(
             d.getUuid(),
          ).execute();
    }
```

In PostgreSql it works, but in Vertica it generate this exception

```
[Vertica][VJDBC](2631) ERROR: Column "uuid" is of type uuid but expression is of type varchar
```

How can I write uuid tu Vertica without generated class? d.getUuid() returns java.Util.UUID

Comment: Not strictly related to your question, but I highly recommend you use either batch or bulk insertion to insert a set of values into a table, to decrease the latency from your many server round trips, if you loop in the client. See also: https://blog.jooq.org/2017/12/18/the-cost-of-jdbc-server-roundtrips/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UUID` type is relatively novel in Vertica. As of jOOQ 3.13, it's not yet supported out of the box:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10073

You'll have to create your own [custom data type binding](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/) for this query, and attach it to your `SQLDataType.UUID`, e.g.

```java
DSL.field(name("uuid"), SQLDataType.UUID.asConvertedDataType(new MyVerticaUUIDBinding()));
```