# JSONB PostgreSQL with jOOQ 3.10

Tags: postgresql, jooq, jsonb

How can I write String variable to PostgreSQL JSONB column without generated classes using jOOQ 3.10?

```
dsl.insertInto(table, Arrays.asList(
    DSL.field("configuration")
))
.values(
    data.getConfiguration()
).execute();
```

I have a json string into data.getConfiguration(), but I get exception

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "configuration" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying
```

Comment: Use the same approach as I've described to you here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61235471/521799

Comment: but SQLDataType has no JsonB type and I have no class for bindings

Comment: You can use any `SQLDataType.*` type for your binding, including e.g. `SQLDataType.VARCHAR`. And you have to write that class for your binding yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the same as for your previous question. [Write a data type binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61235471/521799) (or better: upgrade your jOOQ version!).

```java
DSL.field(name("jsonb_column"), 
  SQLDataType.VARCHAR.asConvertedDataType(new MyJSONBBinding()));
```

[The manual link on the previous answer I've given shows how to do exactly that](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/).